Specific Part Not Showing in PieChart
I have a pie chart displaying various amounts and values. However, I've encountered an issue where a specific segment is not appearing on the chart. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this matter. I've ensured that I'm fetching all values correctly, and upon inspecting them through console.log, everything appears to be working fine. Could AnyOne please help me understand why this discrepancy is occurring?

I've attached an image where you can observe that I've retrieved the amount for '1link,' yet the corresponding segment is not visible on the chart.
here is the code

            ////////////////////////maintenance

            var graphtotmanamontValue = '<%= graphtotmanamont.Text %>';
            var graphtotmanamont1lnkValue = '<%= graphtotmanamont1lnk.Text %>';
            var graphtotmanamontkpayValue = '<%= graphtotmanamontkpay.Text %>';
            var graphtotmanamontothrValue = '<%= graphtotmanamontothr.Text %>';

            var outstndngmanamnt = '<%= lbltotaloutstandingamountman.Text%>';
            var splitoutstndngmanamnt = outstndngmanamnt.split(',');
            var splittedoutstndngmanamnt = splitoutstndngmanamnt.join('');


            ////percentage
            var totalmainothramountpercentage = (graphtotmanamontothrValue / graphtotmanamontValue * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
            var totalmain1linkamountpercentage = (graphtotmanamont1lnkValue / graphtotmanamontValue * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
            var outstndngmainprcntg = (splittedoutstndngmanamnt / graphtotmanamontValue * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";


            var Mainchart = new CanvasJS.Chart("MaintenanceChart", {
                animationEnabled: true,
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                data: [{
                    type: "pie",
                    startAngle: 240,
                    yValueFormatString: "##0\"\"",
                    indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { y: parseFloat(splittedoutstndngmanamnt), label: "O/S ", toolTipContent: "Outstanding Receieved : " + outstndngmainprcntg },
                        { y: parseFloat(graphtotmanamontkpayValue), label: " KPay" },
                        { y: parseFloat(graphtotmanamontothrValue), label: " Others", toolTipContent: "Others Receieved : " + totalmainothramountpercentage , color:"#FFC0CB" },
                        { y: parseFloat(graphtotmanamont1lnkValue), label: " 1LINK", toolTipContent: "1 link Receieved : " + totalmain1linkamountpercentage, color: "orange" }
                    ]
                }]
            });

            Mainchart.render();


